# Mock a Service class with dependencies in another Service Class Mockito

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, mockito

I want to Mock a Service class with dependencies in another Service Class Mockito.

**UserService Class**

```
@Service
class UserService(
    val userRepository: UserRepository,
    val userRoleRepository: UserRoleRepository,
    val jwtGenerator: JwtGenerator,
    val emailService: EmailService
)
```

**AdminService Class**

```
@Service
class AdminService(
    val userService: UserService,
    val userRepository: UserRepository,
    val adminRepository: AdminRepository
)
```

Now I'm trying to write unit test with these classes as follows

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class AdminServiceTests {

private lateinit var createAdmin: CreateAdmin

@Mock
lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository

@Mock
lateinit var userRoleRepository: UserRoleRepository

@Mock
lateinit var jwtGenerator: JwtGenerator

@Mock
lateinit var emailService: EmailService

@InjectMocks
lateinit var userService: UserService

@Mock
lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository // Conflicting declarations

@Mock
lateinit var adminRepository: AdminRepository

@InjectMocks
lateinit var adminService: AdminService

@Before
fun setup() {
    this.createAdmin = CreateAdmin().apply {
        email = "admin@gmail.com"
        name = "admin"
        password = "qwerty"
        phone = 9873555555555
    }
}

@Test
fun testCreateAdmin() {
    val result = adminService.createAdmin(createAdmin)
    Assert.assertEquals(true, result)
}
}
```

Please advice how to mock the userService inside AdminService with all the   four dependencies injected

Answer (score 2):

You can create object of UserService with its dependencies as mocked objects and then use it as a dependency in AdminServiceTests.

Comment: krishna Murari but both services have userRepository as common dependency

Comment: I have edited the question as you suggested please have a look and tell what to change

Comment: @Mohanraj It would not matter you are only creating  mock objects
 Mock - UserRepository , UserRoleRepository ,JwtGenerator , EmailService ,AdminRepository
create object  of UserService of above required mock objects. 
Then create object of AdminService with object of UserService and UserRepository ,AdminRepository as mock objects
I suggest it would be a better design to create a StorageService and put all repositories inside it .

Comment: what i am suggesting is create a simple object of UserService with its required dependencies as mocked objects .
Then create object of AdminService using UserService object and other dependencies as mocked ones. You can google that how to do it.
I am not familiar with kotlin .
I write tests in groovy and spock.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Gradle & Spring, add this plugin to your build.gradle

```
plugins {
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.3.72"
}
```

Mockito should then work without having to mock the dependencies of the service:

```
val userService = Mockito.mock(UserService::class.java)
```